# загрузка заказов (товары с модификациями) с сайта на МойСклад commerceML

Tags: мойсклад-api

Возникла проблемка. Гугл не помог. Документация битрикса тоже(

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/xml/documents.php

При загрузке заказов с сайта на МойСклад, товары сохраняются без модификации и обрезается часть названия в фигурных скобках.

```
<Товар>
    <Ид>u286hhMpg7B6L0aAvnriN3#GlZu3MTNi8aSN9MYIrH9V2</Ид>
    <Наименование>Big boy "Cookie" (120 мл, 0 мг)</Наименование>
    <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>160.0000</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
    <Количество>1</Количество>
    <Сумма>160.0000</Сумма>
    <Скидки>
    <Скидка>
    <УчтеноВСумме>false</УчтеноВСумме>
    <Сумма>0</Сумма>
    </Скидка>
    </Скидки>
    <ЗначенияРеквизитов>
        <ЗначениеРеквизита>
            <Наименование>ТипНоменклатуры</Наименование>
            <Значение>Товар</Значение>
        </ЗначениеРеквизита>
    </ЗначенияРеквизитов>
</Товар>
```

в результате получается аналогично загрузке товара без модификации

```
<Ид>u286hhMpg7B6L0aAvnriN3</Ид>
<Наименование>Big boy "Cookie"</Наименование>
```

Внешние ключи правильные 100%, иначе создается новый товар.
Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, или есть идеи.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

В настройках синхронизации МойСклад есть чекбокс "Создавать модификации товаров"

Comment: А если так попробовать: `Big boy "Cookie" \(120 мл, 0 мг\)` ?

Comment: Не вижу у вас фигурных скобок... Если что, фигурные скобки - это вот такие: `{}`

Comment: не у всех ИМ есть работа с модификациями (в МС). 
в настрйоках у тех, у кого есть возможность - есть флаг.
чтобы работать с модификацими в мс нужно его проставить в true.

Comment: Да спасибо. Действительно ломал голову с кодом, а дело в настройках. В настройках синхронизации МойСклад есть чекбокс "Создавать модификации товаров"